# Is there anything like `L2Sql IMultipleResults` in `Entity Framework 4`?

Tags: linq-to-sql, .net-4.0, entity-framework-4

In Linq 2 Sql, we can retrieve multiple resultsets from the same sp if we know the sequence of tables returned using `IMultipleResults` , `ResultType` and `GetResult<>`.

I am sure, there must be a method in entity framework 4 for doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would think so, wouldn't you. :)

They couldn't sneak it in time for EF4.

In the meantime, you've got 2 options:

1. Use the [**EF Extensions**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFExtensions) project.
2. Use [**ObjectContext.Translate**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466384.aspx). You still need to iterate through the DataReader using classic ADO.NET though.

Check out this [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/04/12/announcing-the-release-of-entity-framework-4.aspx), look for the comment from Danny Simmons to explain the above.